# T1 fontenc - text not searchable

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

Whenever I use the T1 fontenc, the text of the output PDF cannot be searched. You can find a MWE below, the `pdflatex` output [here](https://pastebin.com/rruhNJPf) and the log file [here](https://pastebin.com/c0y9hSry).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\section{Hola amigo}
Todo bien
\end{document}
```

Obviously if I delete the `fontenc` package from preamble the text is searchable without problems.

I don't know if it may be a problem related to my texlive distro (I'm on ArchLinux).

Comment: It works fine for me on windows. Search and copy&paste works e.g. in sumatra or adobe. Which viewer do you use? And can you make the pdf available?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Maybe you are right. I tested different viewers, but they all relied upon mupdf as backend. After switching to PDF XChange or Xournal the search worked again. I think it may be a problem with the `mupdf` libraries instead of the `texlive` ones. I will provide the PDF in a few sec anyway.

Comment: drive.google.com/open?id=1vmpiUcqLDGYO0lCAvjkWFto2HxLdiN7p

Comment: The problem is related to MuPdf and how it treats tiny spaces as qualified spaces. Relevant links for those affected
https://tug.org/pipermail/pdftex/2019-December/009162.html
https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=701979

Comment: Hm. I can't test but I do find it quite odd that mupdf should treat space so wrongly only with T1-encoding.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't know if it's specifically related to T1 encoding, but surely leaving out the package removed all those strange spaces.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a viewer issue.

Answer (score 0):

When using Computer Modern fonts as you are (I see `cm-super` in your logs, good), the package `cmap` would help.

On the other hand, it is better to use Latin Modern fonts instead, and have `glyphtounicode` part for copy/paste:

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1
```

However, there are some limitations with `T1` and copy/paste listed here, e.g. having Croatian `Đ` in PDF, and copying it would give you the Icelandic `Ð` (Eth) - not the same character.

More (light) details on this matter here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cork_encoding#Supported_languages

Complete encoding definition with many details and explanations: http://www.tug.org/fontname/ec.enc

Comment: I tried your solution, but it still didn't work. I avoided special characters at all to show how the problem doesn't seem to be related to that. I also checked that the `cmap` package is installed and up to date.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vmpiUcqLDGYO0lCAvjkWFto2HxLdiN7p

Comment: Have you tried the variant with Latin Modern? From the other comments, I see that the root cause might be the PDF viewer as well. Adobe Reader follows all the standards and does not have any troubles.

Comment: You definitely have troubles with PDF viewer, not with LaTeX.

Comment: Sure I had tried it before. I think you may be correct on the viewer.